# create Pandas dataFrame from lists while preserving datatypes

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am new to using pandas with python. I am creating a new data frame from the following lists:

```
countries = ['Russian Fed.', 'Norway', 'Canada', 'United States',
             'Netherlands', 'Germany', 'Switzerland', 'Belarus',
             'Austria', 'France', 'Poland', 'China', 'Korea', 
             'Sweden', 'Czech Republic', 'Slovenia', 'Japan',
             'Finland', 'Great Britain', 'Ukraine', 'Slovakia',
             'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Australia', 'Croatia', 'Kazakhstan']

gold = [13, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
silver = [11, 5, 10, 7, 7, 6, 3, 0, 8, 4, 1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
bronze = [9, 10, 5, 12, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

What I have is this:

```
a = np.array( [a, g, s, b] ).T
labels = ['countries', 'gold', 'silver', 'bronze']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a, columns = labels)
```

It works but the last 3 columns appear as strings instead of ints. Is there a better way to construct the dataframe while the last 3 columns are inferred ints without having to convert them to ints after creating the dataframe? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the data frame from a dictionary where the values are the lists and keys are the labels/columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'countries': countries, 'gold': gold, 'silver': silver, 'bronze':bronze})

df.dtypes

#bronze        int64
#countries    object
#gold          int64
#silver        int64
#dtype: object
```